# How to get the value of task's "Display on Timeline"?

Tags: mpxj

I'm using MPXJ 7.8.1 to read the MS Project file(.mpp), but I can't find a API to get the value of the field "Display on Timeline" on Task info.

Is there a way to get the value of this field?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately at present there isn't a way to retrieve this field using MPXJ. I've had a quick look and it appears that this flag may be stored as part of the view data for a Gantt chart, but I've not had the time to dig into this in enough detail to extract it. I'll add it to the todo list!

Comment: Hi Jon, this field is still not supported in version 8.0.5, do you already have plans to support this field in future versions?

Comment: Apologies, I haven't had the time to look into this.

Comment: Hi Jon, I created an issue on github: https://github.com/joniles/mpxj/issues/148.